# Reachability Resolves Host Name But Host Name Cannot be Pinged

Tags: ios, reachability

I used the Network Utility in Mac to ping the host name which is something like: ssads.ads.asd (Unfortunately, I cannot share the exact address). I was not able to ping it and it timed out.

```
 // make sure that the host is reachable
    NetworkStatus status = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"somehostnamethatIcannotping"] currentReachabilityStatus];
```

When I used the above code it always resolves into ReachableUsingWifi. How can it be reachable if I cannot ping it?

Answer (score 0):

The machine on the other end might be blocking or ignoring pings. Not all machines that are reachable respond to pings.

Comment: Thanks! But in that case shouldn't the Reachability API return some error instead of saying that it succeeded.

Comment: A look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_ReachConnect/SC_ReachConnect.html) implies that it determines if the remote host is reachable if the packet is able to leave the device, and that it doesn't guarantee the other end will get it or send a response.